# Nut and bolt terminology. What is the name of the fixing in the image?

Tags: part-identification, bolts

What would be the name for the cylindrical item in the image below?

I have tried searching for stand-off, collar, riser, (and the frankly ridiculous 'bolt pipe', which throws up some unexpected answers) but I'm not getting anywhere fast. This image is from a kit for fitting side panels to a motorcycle. The cylinder is used to hide the bolt thread and offset the panel from the frame slightly. Any ideas?

[image: Four small bolts with countersunk washers and an unidentified cylindrical item.]

Comment: Try "spacer",  A search for this term gets images of that part.

Comment: Sleave or bushing. It could be an adapter as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @FredWilson says that's a spacer. You can find them in a variety of sizes at most "real" hardware stores (at least you can in the US). The place to look is in the fastener section in the boxes of specialty parts.

Failing that you can make them from a length of suitably sized pipe or tubing. Ideally the spacer should be similar in diameter to a washer (both OD and ID) so that it will support the fastener and not allow the head to be pulled through the material.

BTW - the other item is called a finish washer.